# can you have multiple GO's inside of an BEGIN TRY CATCH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to modify a procedure by separating the update statements inside of the procedure with `GO` so that they are batched up.

Is it legal to put multiple `GO`'s inside of end try catch? The reason I ask is because when I execute the `ALTER` statement on the procedure, nothing happens. It's just executing and not stopping.

```
USE [CRM_Staging]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CustomerProduct_Import]    Script Date: 04/10/2014 12:38:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomerProduct_Import]
(
    @LogId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
)
AS


BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

select.....

go

update...

go

update...

go

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
    RETURN 1 --@Success
END
```

and I also have squiggly lines here, `"expecting conversation"`

[image]

what am i doing wrong?

the full script is here:
http://pastebin.com/WDmqwn2N

Comment: I think we need to see what is inside the try to help you. You can have multiple statements in 1 block.

Comment: thanks so much, i've updated http://pastebin.com/WDmqwn2N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GO is a batch separator. The first GO inside a stored procedure ends the procedure's definition, IOW everything after the GO is not considered a part of the procedure. You cannot have a GO inside a procedure.

So, whatever you're trying to do, it's not the proper way.

Comment: got it! thank you. so should i just do start transaction commit transaction to separate the updates?

Comment: Why would you? Don't you want to have all the updates inside the procedure go all or nothing?

Comment: Yes, you can use COMMIT transaction - know that the StoredProc will commit at the end.

Comment: i dont want the updates running in parallel, i want one to run and then finish, and then the next to run and then finish etc

Comment: It's the default behaviour, every update will open and commit it's own separate transaction if not explicitely told otherwise.